# Autocomplete off in HTML5

Tags: html, autocomplete

I have tried both autocomplete="off" and autocomplete="false" in HTML5 form but It's not working in chrome version (73.0.3683.103).

Comment: have a look at this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Answer (score 3):

## Disable HTML Form Input Autocomplete and Autofill

1. Add `autocomplete="off"` onto `<form>` element;
2. Add hidden `<input>` with `autocomplete="false"` as a first children element of the form.

```html
<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="">
    <input autocomplete="false" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">
    ...
```

This formation is going to prevent Chrome and Firefox to offer autofill and autocomplete for all input fields inside the form. (as discussed [here](https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8))

Although it is *known* that some browsers ignore this; there's a full discussion in the link attached to this thread of possible fixes.

> Now works for me in Chrome 72.0.3626.121 having never worked
>   previously.
>
> I had been using `<input type="text" id="something" pattern="[ \S]+" role="presentation" autocomplete="nope">` but that now doesn't work.

You can read more about `autocomplete` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).

You can also opt to use some sort of [library](https://terrylinooo.github.io/jquery.disableAutoFill/) *if relevant*.

There doesn't seem to be one working solution from the investigation above though.

Read more about this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill).

Comment: Thanks for MDN link, it explains the source of problem.